# How to get the system's region with React Native instead of the app's region, which is based on the app's selected language

Tags: android, ios, react-native

On Android and iOS devices, there are two places to get/set the language and region.

1. is the system settings language/region.
2. is the app's language/region.

I'd like to know how to get the system's region.

All the packages and methods I've come across so far get the app's region.